# javaのif文について

Tags: java

引数と実行結果が同じになってしまいます。
デバッグで止まるのに、値がかわらないのはどうしてでしょうか？
エラーはでておりません。
おしえていただきたいです。

---

**実行結果**

```
20092812345
```

**ソースコード**

```
public String net(String in) {
    char[] result = in.toCharArray();

    for(int i = '0'; i < result.length; i++)

        if(result[i] == '0') {
            result[i] = '9';
        }else {
            --result[i];
        }

    String result01 = String.copyValueOf(result);

    return result01;
}

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        angouka test01 = new angouka();
        System.out.println(test01.net("20092812345"));

    }
}
```

Comment: `for` 文の範囲があいまいです。 `{ }` をきちんと付けるとどうなりますか？

Comment: for(int i = '0'; i < result.length; i++){

        if(result[i] == '0') {
            result[i] = '9';
        }else {
            --result[i];
        }
}         上記変更しましたが、実行結果は変わりませんでした。

Comment: 20092812345　　　引数の値と同じままです。　でもデバッグは1行ずつ動きます。

Comment: for文の i = '0'のシングルクオーテーションは必要ですか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for`文の範囲が`'0'`からになっているのが原因です。
下記の修正をすると正しく動くはずです。

修正前: `for(int i = '0'`
修正後: `for(int i = 0`

修正後の出力結果: `19981701234`

char型の'0'とint型の0は[違うもの](https://qiita.com/nkojima/items/d358f99efa71655911ea)です。
ご興味がありましたらリンク先のQiita記事などを取っ掛かりにしてchar型とは何かを勉強してみてください。

Comment: 読ませていただきました！！ありがとうございます！